# How can I convert class CustomObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken) to generic view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, generics, django-rest-framework

I noticed that my Django Swagger Documentation is working properly only when I have generic views with `serializer_class`. I am trying to convert this class to generic view without effects. How can I do this without serializer? Any suggestions?

```
class CustomObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(CustomObtainAuthToken, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'id': token.user_id})
```

At this moment I send only `username` and `password`. In response I get something like this:

```
{
    "token": "23213718fbe2eewq2205f45cb71c27391324ed",
    "id": 8
}
```

Comment: I assume you can just get the auth token directly from the request? so you don't need the `super()` call?

Comment: @CoryMadden I have updated my post. I'm not sure you meant it?

Comment: Can you access the ['token'] data directly from the `request` argument in the `post` method? If so, are you using any other methods of this view, such as the `get` method?

Comment: No, this is the only way to get a token. When frontend want to check token one more time it has to log in again.